# Not able to access my system drive folder in UWP application. always return false when i use Directory.Exists

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

string tallyDirPath = @"D:\Work";

if (Directory.Exists(tallyDirPath))
{

```
            var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(tallyDirPath);

            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
                                 | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                                 | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                                 | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                 | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                 | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                 | NotifyFilters.Security
                                 | NotifyFilters.Size;
```

}

Comment: UWP sandbox? Have you looked at the available manifest options?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does my reply make sense?

Answer (score 0):

As Anders said, UWP apps are running in the sandbox. So UWP apps are not allowed to access some system resources directly like the file system. For example, you can't use the .net APIs that use the file path to get the file. Of course, there are some places that UWP apps could access by default. For more information, please check [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)

If you want to get a file via a path in UWP apps. You have to add the restricted **broadFileSystemAccess** capability in the manifest file. This capability works for APIs in the [Windows.Storage namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage?view=winrt-22621). This means you need to use the Windows.Storage APIs with the file path like [StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync?view=winrt-22621#windows-storage-storagefile-getfilefrompathasync(system-string)).